# Matrix representation of general linear mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}{\text { Let } B \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \text { and define a linear mapping } T : \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \text { by } T(X) :=X B \text { . }} \\ {\begin{array}{ll}{\text {I want to find the matrix representation of T. }}\\
 {} & B={\left(\begin{array}{cc}{1} & {0} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}{0} & {1} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}{0} & {0} \\ {1} & {0}\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}{0} & {0} \\ {0} & {1}\end{array}\right)} \\ {\text { And then find } \operatorname{Tr}(T) \text { and } \operatorname{det}(T)}\end{array}}\end{array}
\end{equation}

---

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but since B is fixed I need  to plug in variables in order to calculate the matrix representation(?)

So to find the matrix representation of $T$ I assume B = $\left(\begin{array}{cc}{a} & {b} \\ {c} & {d}\end{array}\right)$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.

And then $T\left(\begin{array}{cc}{1} & {0} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right)^{\mathcal{B}}=
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c}{a} \\ {b} \\ {0} \\ {0}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}$, calculating these for all the remaining bases results in $T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}{a} & {c} & {0} & {0} \\ {b} & {d} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{0} & {0} & {a} & {c} \\
{0} & {0} & {b} & {d}
\end{array}\right)$. Is this the right way to do this?

And for the Trace: $Tr(T)=a+d+a+d=2a+2d$ and the $det(T) = (ad-bc)^2$.

Is this the right way to find the matrix representation of $T$?

Comment: Careful, $T\left(\begin{array}{cc}{1} & {0} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right)^{\mathcal{B}}=
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c}{a} \\ {b} \\ {0} \\ {0}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}$ is NOT correct! Your codomain consists of  $2 \times 2$- matrices, the correct image in this case is \begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.

Comment: @Riquelme I think noahfr wanted to express the image of $T$ in coordinates, for this he uses column.

Comment: @AlessandroCigna Excatly. I thought that was the right way to do this. (The image of T(..) w.r.t the basis B).

Comment: @noahfr i would write it like this $T\left(\begin{array}{cc}{1} & {0} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right)^{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = a \left(\begin{array}{cc}{1} & {0} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right) + b \left(\begin{array}{cc}{0} & {1} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right) = a \cdot B_1 + b \cdot B_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Only thing I can suppose is that the exercise want the answer in terms of $B$: infact you can say that $$T=\begin{bmatrix} B^t&0\\0&B^t\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $tr (T)=2tr (B)$ and $\det (T)=\det^2(B)$.

Comment: I think this is even better. Thank you.